# Visual C# check type of array elements with lambda expression

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, plugins, lambda

I have an array that contains various type of elements.

I am trying to construct a lambda expression that will evaluate the if clause true if a specific type exists in the array.

I was trying the following and many different approaches but I don't seem to get it right:

```cs
var arraySourceText = EditorController.ActiveDocument
                                      .ActiveSegmentPair
                                      .Source
                                      .AllSubItems
                                      .ToArray();

if (arraySourceText.Any(o => o.GetType()) == typeof(string))
{
   intStartingPH++;
}
```

Any advice is welcome.

Note: the `arraySourceText` is an API `IEnumerable` with custom types. I just assumed `string` for simplicity in the pseudocode.

*Update:* Because the type is not exposed by the API, only the name of the type, the workaround was based on Byyo's correction. I wrote a separate method to check the name of the type and return a `bool`:

```cs
var arraySourceText = EditorController.ActiveDocument
                                      .ActiveSegmentPair
                                      .Source
                                      .AllSubItems
                                      .ToArray();

string typePH = "PlaceholderTag";

if (arraySourceText.Any(o => IsMatchTypeString(typePH, o)))
    {
        intStartingPH++;
    }

//Then the below method does the check:

static bool IsMatchTypeString(string testtype, params object[] items)
{
    if (items.Length == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (testtype == items[0].GetType().ToString())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your parenthesis are wrong (maybe a typo though): `arraySourceText.Any(o => o.GetType()== typeof(string)`

Comment: Thanks for reply, I added the declaration of the array and a clarifying note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there seems to be error in your parenthesis

```
                                        v                  v 
if (arraySourceText.Any(o => o.GetType()) == typeof(string)) // your approach
if (arraySourceText.Any(o => o.GetType() == typeof(string))) // correct approach
```

instead of checking each element to be `string`, you check the result of `Any()` to be `typeof(string)`

Comment: Thanks. I see. I corrected that, but then I realized after compiling my plugin that in fact this part of the API is not publicly exposed. So I screwed. I need to rewrite my code to work around it... But thanks for looking.

Comment: Eureka! I did a work around and I used only the shallow version of the type by converting it `ToString()` and then checking its string value. I wrote a static method, which does this and returns true if match and false if not. But your answer lead me to the solution on the lambda expression part!